# reformating a text file

Tags: bash, cmd, cygwin

I've looked for existing answers, but am at a loss.

I need to take a plain text file:

1 - round decimals to tenths

2 - last group of numbers need to be four characters long, using zero to fill

3 - remove periods - found sed solution

4 - remove spaces  - found sed solution

here is an example of the file I'm working with

```
5.41   3.08  795
4.82   2.69   19
3.60   2.83    8
4.24   3.10 1559
```

needs to be changed to:

```
54310795
48270019
36280008
42311559
```

Thanks - Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it in one-shot with awk:

```
 awk '{$0=sprintf("%.1f%.1f%04d", $1,$2,$3);gsub(/\./,"")}1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat file
5.41   3.08  795
4.82   2.69   19
3.60   2.83    8
4.24   3.10 1559

kent$  awk '{$0=sprintf("%.1f%.1f%04d", $1,$2,$3);gsub(/\./,"")}1' file
54310795
48270019
36280008
42311559
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great.  I have no clue what any of it is tho.

Comment: @user2052255 `sprintf()` prints a formatted string that is assigned back to `$0` (the input line). `%.1f` formats a floating point number to a single decimal (rounding the number accordingly). `%04d` formats an integer number to 4 digits, left-padded with zeroes. Finally `gsub()` replaces the decimal dots with empty strings, thus removing the dots.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: And `1` prints the result.:) Nice trick!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the explanation. TrueY thank you too.

Comment: I need follow-up help.  I had to install cygwin and this script on Win7 (64bit).  Now I lose the carrage return. I get the right info, but all in one line