# using sed, awk, or sort for csv manipulation

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file that needs a lot of manipulation. Maybe by using awk and sed?

input:

```
"Sequence","Fat","Protein","Lactose","Other Solids","MUN","SCC","Batch Name"
1,4.29,3.3,4.69,5.6,11,75,"35361305a"
2,5.87,3.58,4.41,5.32,10.9,178,"35361305a"
3,4.01,3.75,4.75,5.66,12.2,35,"35361305a"
4,6.43,3.61,3.56,4.41,9.6,275,"35361305a"
```

final output:

```
43330075995647
59360178995344
40380035995748
64360275964436
```

I'm able to get through some of it going step by step.
How do I test specific columns for a value over 9.9 and replace it with 9.9 ?
Also, is there a way to combine any of these steps?

remove first line:

```
tail -n +2 test.csv > test1.txt
```

remove commas:

```
sed 's/,/ /g' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

remove quotes:

```
sed 's/"//g' test2.txt > test3.txt
```

remove columns 1 and 8 and 
reorder remaining columns as 1,2,6,5,4,3:

```
sort test3.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $8 "\t" $7 "\t" $6 "\t" $5}' test4.txt
```

test new columns 1,2,4,5,6 -  if the value is over 9.9, replace it with 9.9

```
How should I do this step?
```

solution for following parts were found in a previous question - [reformating a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046624/reformating-a-text-file)
columns 1,2,4,5,6 round decimals to tenths
column 3 needs to be four characters long, using zero to left fill
remove periods and spaces

```
awk '{$0=sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s%.1f%.1f%.1f", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);gsub(/ /,"0");gsub(/\./,"")}1' test5.txt > test6.txt
```

Comment: Which bit can't you do? At the moment this seems like a list of features that you'd like implemented, rather than a question.

Comment: fair enough - test columns 1,2,4,5,6 - if the value is over 9.9, replace it with 9.9

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to make it clear which part you're having a problem with.

Comment: "column 4 round to whole number" - it doesn't look like that in your output. That would mean that all those 99s and 96s would be 10s

Comment: good catch, the value needs to stay at 9.9 and not round up to 10

Comment: I will try to reword the question to make it clearer what I need help with

Comment: In such situations, I find it's always better to use a proper scripting language, such as perl or python. It's generally more straight forward to implement that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output you want from the original file. Note that in the question you specified  - note that in the question you specified "column 4 round to whole number" but in the desired output you had rounded it to one decimal place instead:

```
awk -F'[,"]+' 'function m(x) { return x < 9.9 ? x : 9.9 } 
NR > 1 { 
    s = sprintf("%.1f%.1f%04d%.1f%.1f%.1f", m($2),m($3),$7,m($6),m($5),m($4))
    gsub(/\./, "", s)
    print s
}' test.csv
```

I have specified the field separator as any number of commas and double quotes together, so this "parses" your CSV format for you without requiring any additional steps.

The function `m` returns the minimum of 9.9 and the number you pass to it.

Output:

```
43330075995647
59360178995344
40380035995748
64360275964436
```

Comment: You sure about `%04d`? :)

Comment: @konsolebox it looks like an integer field, so this fulfills the "column 3 needs to be four characters long, using zero to left fill" part.

Comment: @TomFenech Thank you for your help solving this, and for having me clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

The three first in one go:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/"/,"");$1=$1} NR>1' test.csc
1 4.29 3.3 4.69 5.6 11 75 35361305a
2 5.87 3.58 4.41 5.32 10.9 178 35361305a
3 4.01 3.75 4.75 5.66 12.2 35 35361305a
4 6.43 3.61 3.56 4.41 9.6 275 35361305a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tail -n +2 file | sort -u | awk -F , '
    {
        $0 = $1 FS $2 FS $6 FS $5 FS $4 FS $3
        for (i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
            if ($i > 9.9)
                $i = 9.9
        $0 = sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s%.0f%.1f%.1f", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
        gsub(/ /, "0"); gsub(/[.]/, "")
        print
    }
'
```

Or

```
< file awk -F , '
    NR > 1 {
        $0 = $1 FS $2 FS $6 FS $5 FS $4 FS $3
        for (i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
            if ($i > 9.9)
                $i = 9.9
        $0 = sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s%.0f%.1f%.1f", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
        gsub(/ /, "0"); gsub(/[.]/, "")
        print
    }
'
```

Output:

```
104309964733
205909954436
304009964838
406409643636
```

Comment: That output is completely different to what the OP wanted.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes I don't think the question is serious either so it doesn't really matter.